# psycopg2 can't see my PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm on Windows, with a 32bit install of python 2.6.6 and psycopg2.

When psycopg2 tries to connect, it gets an `OperationalError`:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=your_database user=postgres password=xxxx host=127.0.0.1:5432")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "127.0.0.1:5432" to address: Unknown server error
```

I am able to connect to PostgreSQL instance with pgAdmin3 on `127.0.0.1:5432`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=your_database user=postgres password=xxxx host=127.0.0.1 port=5432")
```

Comment: I think it's better idea to use `psycopg2.connect(database='your_database', user='postgres', password='xxxx')` Named parameters are better (more readable) than connection string and localhost and 5432 are default values so you don't have to pass them at all.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the port `:5432` from the `host` name worked for me.