# psycopg2 can’t connect to postgres database in dockerized Python-Flask app

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I’m working on a Python-Flask project that has one docker container for the web app and another docker container for the postgres database.  I use a virtualenv to manage all of my dependencies.  After having some initial issues with getting `psycopg2` installed, I now have all of the dependencies installed. 
But, I get a `psycopg2` error whenever I try to run `flask db migrate` from the command line.  See a snippet from the error below:

```sh
File "/home/myuser/Workspace/GroupName/MyApp/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/myuser/Workspace/GroupName/MyApp/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
 postgres:
   restart: always
   image: postgres:latest
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: MyApp
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fakepassword
     POSTGRES_DB: MyApp-dev
   volumes:
     - ./container_data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   ports:
     - "5432:5432"

 web:
   restart: always
   build:
      context: .
      args:
      - DOCKER_BUILD_ENV
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/web/Dockerfile
   environment:
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
     AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}"
     S3_BUCKET_NAME: "${S3_BUCKET_NAME}"
     APPROVE_REGISTRATIONS: "${APPROVE_REGISTRATIONS}"
     FLASK_APP: app
     FLASK_ENV: "${FLASK_ENV:-development}"
   volumes:
     - ./MyApp/:/usr/src/app/MyApp/:z
   links:
     - postgres:postgres
   expose:
     - "3000"
   command: scripts/entrypoint.sh
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
```

Here are excerpts from the `dockerfile` that are related to `requirements.txt` and the database.

```sh
.....
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir virtualenv
RUN virtualenv /ve
ENV PATH=/ve/bin:$PATH
........

USER www-data

COPY requirements.txt dev-requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ARG DOCKER_BUILD_ENV
RUN test "${DOCKER_BUILD_ENV}" = production || pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r dev-requirements.txt

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn

COPY create_db.py test_data.py /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 3000

ENV PATH="/usr/src/app/geckodriver:${PATH}"
ENV SECRET_KEY *************
ENV SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI postgresql://MyApp:fakepassword@postgres/MyApp-dev

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/MyApp

CMD ["scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is `entrypoint.sh`.  I don't think this caused the error because I hit the error when running `flask db migrate` from the command line, not from this script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${DOCKER_BUILD_ENV:-}" == "production" ]; then
    flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000
else
    yarn build
    yarn watch &
    flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000
fi
```

I looked up similar questions, like [psycopg2 can't see my PostgreSQL instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903006/psycopg2-cant-see-my-postgresql-instance) but I don’t have anywhere in my code that I explicitly use `psycopg2` to create a connection.  The closest thing is at the top of `models.py`, where I put:

`db = SQLAlchemy()`

I ran `docker ps` and confirmed that both of the services are running.

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a1e6891161d1        myapp_web   "scripts/entrypoint.…"   57 minutes ago      Up 57 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   myapp_web_1
bfa83d282ac7        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 57 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   myapp_postgres_1
```

Any ideas why I can’t run `flask db migrate` or `flask db stamp head` from the command line when I'm in the virtualenv?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  For instance, trim the Dockerfile down to the minimum to install the application (and not an extra Web browser or Node build chain), but do include things like the `entrypoint.sh` script that shows where you're trying to run `flask db migrate`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sure, I'll reduce the information in the question.  I try to include as much information as possible when asking a question on StackOverflow, in part because I've previously been reprimanded for including code snippets that didn't include import statements.  However, I realize it's easier for people to read through shorter questions.

Comment: I think the problem in the connection details. Are you sure that the hostname is "postgres" not "locahost" ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a breaking change as reported in the [docker-library/postgres GitHub issues #681](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/681) which caused this.  The solution in my case was to follow as per instructions in docker logs:

```
   Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
   You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD for the superuser. Use
   "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set it in "docker run".

   You may also use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust to allow all connections
   without a password. This is *not* recommended. See PostgreSQL
   documentation about "trust":
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

In the docker compose, I added the following environmental variable:

```
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

The latter environmental variable allows anybody to connect to the database so it is recommended setting a password as this is an unsafe workaround.